# implement Tranactions with TypeOrm and Nestjs

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using Typeorm with MongoDb .

I wanna to do some example **transaction**

But it doesn't work .

I mean **it doesn't roll back** on error .

below is avatar.repository.ts

```js
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectDataSource, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Avatar } from '../entity/avatar.entity';
import { Repository, EntityManager, QueryRunner, DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { AvatarRepository } from '../../domain/repository/avatarRepository.interface';
import { AvatarM } from '../../domain/model/avatar';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseAvatarRepository implements AvatarRepository {


    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Avatar) private readonly avatarEntity: Repository<AvatarM>,
        private readonly dataSource: DataSource,
        private readonly manager: EntityManager

    ) { }

    async transTest() {
        const a = this.avatarEntity.create({ userId: 1, hashedName: 'aaa' }) // this query will be saved successfully
        const b = this.avatarEntity.create({ userId: 2, hashedName: 'bbb' }) // this query will encounter error beacuse it is duplicated 
        await this.dataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
            await transactionalEntityManager.save(a)
            await transactionalEntityManager.save(b)
        })
    }

}
```

the problem is that when There is an error in send action , it doesn't roll back the first query .

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Typeorm driver for MongoDB does not support transactions. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/mongodb/MongoDriver.ts#L75

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transactions in typeorm with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144140/transactions-in-typeorm-with-mongodb)